# iPhoto 9.5.1 deleting photos and library!

Tags: time-machine, backup, photos.app, photos

iPhoto 9.5.1 recently just deleted my photos. Was there an auto upgrade? it happened overnight so I was not on the computer. I cannot find all those photos in iPhoto/Library under User. Any suggestions? It seems that Time Machine does not back up iPhoto in Mavericks, so I've been reading. I cannot find the iPhoto file anywhere in Time Machine.

Where are those photos that were suddenly gone MIA?

Comment: your console would have keep a log of activity while you were sleeping :)

Answer (score 1):

OK. Please follow those steps : 
Open IPhoto 9.5.1 while pressing the "alt" key. Select "New". Name it Iphoto Library 2 for exemple. Press Enter, let IPhoto open.

Now, go into your Pictures folder. Find the IPhoto Library. Click right onto it, choose "Show packets".

Find the "Masters" Folder. Drag it with your mouse and drop it inside the IPhoto's window. The bloody app should now import all your photos.

Quit IPhoto. You can now delete the old IPhoto Library and rename your new IPhoto Library 2 into IPhoto Library.